# Issue with Bing Search API which returns only relatedSearches and not WebPages

Tags: search, bing

Here is the query on Bing.com:

[image: Full Bing URL]

Here is my API Call:

[image: Full API call URL]

Here are the results from the API (it only contains RelatedSearches, not WebPages in the JSON):

> {"_type": "SearchResponse", "relatedSearches": {"id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#RelatedSearches", "value": [{"text": "abney elementary home of the little spartans", "displayText": "abney elementary home of the little spartans", "webSearchUrl":

Answer (score 0):

@Chris query which you are parsing in the URL is doing trouble. If I will change  query from site:www.jrmc.org stuart ABNEY to www.jrmc.org stuart ABNEY I will get result in both bing.com and Bing API.
However I am not sure about this and still trying to figure it out. I will get back to you with more appropriate solution, meanwhile you can change the query and try.

Comment: Ok I will try, but I really need to keep site:www.jrmc.org as I want Bing to give me only pages at this website for this search.

Answer (score 0):

From the full API call URL you shared you are URL-encoding responseFilter=Webpages as part of the q (query) parameter, but it should be a separate URL parameter:

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/bing/v5.0/search?q=site%3Awww.sjchs.org+Joseph+F+ABRUTZ+JR&responseFilter=Webpages

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. It appears that the Bing API, when provided with a search keyword as a parameter, fails to return results related to it if there are no matches. In such cases, it does not include the `webPages` property in the response.